# model keys not passing to other model's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I am implementing a nested form in Rails, and here is the code which implements that

```
<% @project.features.each do |fet| %>
    <%= "#{fet.name} #{fet.id}" %>
    <%= link_to "Add task", new_feature_task_path(fet) %>
<% end %>
```

When I omit the `link_to` and run the page, it successfully render the `fet.name` and `fet.id` on the webpage, which indicates that the object is currently held in `fet`, But when I try to pass the `fet` value to the `new_feature_task_path` it shows error , as if no value is passesd->

[image]
*(I am implementing nested forms for different models)*

**For further reference I am including the routes.rb-**

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :features, shallow: true do
      resources :tasks, shallow: true
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try `<%= link_to "Add task", new_feature_task_path(feature_id: fet.id) %>`, if you're be sure `fet.id` can't return `nil`.

Comment: NOw it shows  `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tasks", :feature_id=>nil, :id=>"4"}, possible unmatched constraints: [:feature_id]`

Comment: What's `fet`, what kind of object?

Comment: I guess is not going to fix your issue but I think your last `shallow: true` is useless.